# Laravel - Store selected data in session

Tags: php, laravel, session

The data in session lives only until page refresh:( How can make it live longer ?

index.blade.php

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {!! Form::select('first_name', $firstNames) !!}
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

DashboardController.php

```
public function getIndex( Request $request )
{

    $this->data['online_users'] = \DB::table('tb_users')->orderBy('last_activity','desc')->limit(10)->get();
    $this->data['firstNames'] = \DB::table('tb_users')->orderBy('first_name')->lists('first_name', 'id');
    print_r($this->data['firstNames']);
    \Session::put('firstNames',Input::get('first_name'));
    $this->data['active'] = '';
    return view('dashboard.index',$this->data);
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing it in the session, exactly? This kind of thing can be passed from the controller to the view directly, and should be.

Comment: Firstly check the result what is coming from the database for your query by keeping print_r($this->data['firstNames']);

Comment: `print_r($this->data['firstNames']);` retuned correct `Array ( [1] => Root [4] => TFS )`

Comment: Hi Scott. Could you please be more specific. This is my first task to store data in session. I have been working on it for a few days with no progress

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
return view('dashboard.index')->with(['data', $this->data]);
```

Comment: I am getting this error with the above **Undefined variable: pageTitle**

Comment: I got the same error. This maybe helpful for you I showed the whole Controller function above.

Comment: I forgot the brackets

Answer (score 0):

Use `compact`

```
$data['online_users'] = \DB::table('tb_users')->orderBy('last_activity','desc')->limit(10)->get();
$data['firstNames'] = \DB::table('tb_users')->orderBy('first_name')->lists('first_name', 'id');
$data['firstName'] = Input::get('first_name'));
$data['active'] = '';
return view('dashboard.index', compact('data'));
```

then you will be able to access all values:

- `{{ $data['firstNames'] }}`
- `{{ $data['firstName'] }}`
- `{{ $data['online_users'] }}`
- `{{ $data['active'] }}`

No need for session in this case

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am getting `Undefined variable: pageTitle` error. You have an idea ?

Comment: Do you have this variable in your blade template? Make sure that it is set to a value

Comment: Hi. I removed the `pageTitle` varible from blade template. Now I am getting no error but the session data is still the same, living only until I refresh the page

Comment: why do you need a session, when you refresh the request might not be set for `Input::get('first_name'))`

Comment: I will print this selection `{{ Session::get('first_name') }}` in a readonly field while I am posting form. When other users login to system they will see only rows which contains their usernames with this query `return "  WHERE first_name = '".Auth::user()->first_name."' ";`

Comment: This query is working well. I just need to store this `first_name` selection in session during the form posts.

Comment: If you have any other solution for this, you are welcome.

Comment: Thank you very much. This can work. We are getting closer to result. I am getting **Undefined variable: firstNames** Any idea ?

Comment: @Selim you have to use the `$data` variable since it is an associative array, `{{ $data['firstNames'] }}`

Comment: Thank you very much. I am out now. This is the first thing I will check tom morning. I keep you posted.

Comment: Hi. I exactly the same codes you gave. Now I am getting error from **ErrorException in helpers.php line 469** `htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /home/univer/public_html/univer/resources/views/dashboard/index.blade.php)` Any idea?